# How do you specify a fop config file for fop.bat in ant script

Tags: ant, apache-fop

I have a statement in ant script that calls fop.bat
`<property name="ant4docbook.fop" value="${basedir}/content/support/lib/fop-1.1/fop.bat" />`

How do you specify fop config file "-c cfg.xml" either in ant script or in fop.bat file itself. I tried single quotes within double quotes but did not work.

Comment: That will depend on how the script uses this property.  Can you find the other part of the script where it uses the ant4docbook.fop property and share that also?  You should be able to do a find for ${ant4docbook.fop}

Comment: Someone else had added this to my script, can't locate where it is used, appears not to be used. Here is target they placed it in. `<target name="if_windows" depends="checkos" if="isWindows">
    <property name="ant4docbook.fop" value="${basedir}/content/support/lib/fop-1.1/fop.bat" />
  </target>`   As a more general question how can I add `-c config.xml` at the end of fop.bat  in the value assignment. Or is it more complicated.

Comment: If that property is not used in your ant script, then there is probably nothing you can do in the ant script to get it to take arguments.  I was expecting your ant script to contain an exec element where you could add the arguments.  That property statement does not call the bat file, it's just setting a text variable for use later.

Comment: Thanks I think the other guy thought it was calling the appropriate fop script based on the OS. I will experiment with exec element.